# Find polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $A(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where $a_j=2(3)^j-j^2(-1)^j$ and $A(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2...$ satisfying $a_j=2(3)^j-j^2(-1)^j$

Let $A(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$

Find polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $A(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

I've recognized that the form of $a_j=2(3)^j-j^2(-1)^j$ looks familiar so I tried working backwards to the characteristic polynomial

so

$$a_j=(A)(3)^j-(B+Cj+Dj^2)(-1)^j$$
$$(x-3)(x+1)^3$$
$$x^4-6x^2-8x-3=0$$

which brings me to the recurrence relation

$$a_j-6a_{j-2}-8a_{j-3}-3a_{j-4} = 0$$

Now that I'm here I'm having trouble deciding how to proceed. I'm not entirely sure I'm even on the right track.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've figured this one out, I made an error when creating my characteristic polynomial which led me to an incorrect recurrence relation. Thanks to anyone who took a look though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a three pieces-puzzle:

- $U_a(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant0}a^jx^j=\frac1{1-ax}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant0}ja^jx^j=xU'_a(x)=\frac{ax}{(1-ax)^2}$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant0}j(j-1)a^jx^j=x^2U''_a(x)=\frac{2a^2x}{(1-ax)^3}$

Hence
$$
A=2U_3-U''_{-1}-U'_{-1},$$
that is,
$$
A(x)=\frac2{1-3x}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}-\frac{2x}{(1+x)^3}=\frac2{1-3x}+\frac{x(1-x)}{(1+x)^3},
$$
which yields
$$
f(x)=2(1+x)^3+x(1-x)(1-3x),\quad g(x)=(1-3x)(1+x)^3.
$$